# Cannot connect to database from python script and command line, but can connect with PGadmin - FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, centos7

I know similar questions have been asked about 2000 times, but none of the answer I found so far helped me.

So it's possible for me to connect to my DB via PGAdmin through an SSH tunnel and I can also use `su - postgres psql`, but when I do `su - postgres` and then somthing like `psql -U postgres -h localhost` I get the error `FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"`.

Same thing happens when I try to connect to the database with my python script.

Of coure I tried editing my `pg_hba.conf` file in numerous ways, setting everything to `trust`, `password` or `md5`. Said the same thing every time.

Currently my `pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

`local   all             all                                     md5`

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5`

`host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5`

And yes, I did restart the server inbetween changes. I don't know what the problem here could be, any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally managed to fix this problem!

The error message here is completely misleading. The problem was that "localhost" was not resolved to 127.0.0.1 because the /etc/hosts file had two lines specifying localhost:

`127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4`

and

`::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`

Using 127.0.0.1 or leaving only `::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6` fixed the problem.

Hope this helps someone in the future :)